# How do I automatically publish new content on Drupal 7 site to Twitter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

On my Drupal 7 site, when I create new content (e.g. a blog post), I want that content to automatically publish to my Twitter feed.  In other words, if I create a new blog post, I want notification of that new post published to twitter.  I've done a number of searches on this topic and have not found a solution.  I installed and enabled the twitter module and followed all instructions for configuring the module and registering my app with Twitter.  I can read my Twitter feed into the site but I cannot publish to Twitter.  Can anyone provide instructions for updating my Twitter feed whenever new content is published on my Drupal site?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I found the solution.  Maybe I missed this in the various tutorials and documentation I read but, to get the module to post to Twitter, I had to "Go to Twitter and add and authenticated account" last in the process.  Even though the account was already listed under Administration/Configuration/Web Services/Twitter and all setting correct.  I deleted the account and re-Authenticated the same account.  Then everything worked; content was posted to Twitter and read into Drupal (after running cron).  I tested this process on three different sites and, in all cases, that's how I got the post functionality to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable twitter post and twitter action modules, bundled with twitter module itself.

Go to twitter settings and configure post settings to display on blogs. You would see a checkbox while creating a new blog post saying "Post to twitter". If you tick the checkbox, a message will get posted on twitter.

Alternatively,

Create a rule with following config:

> **Event**: After saving new content
>
> **Condition**: Content is of type blog
>
> **Action**: Post a message on twitter

```
{ "sp_socialshare_feature_post_on_twitter" : {
    "LABEL" : "Post on Twitter",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : true,
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "twitter_actions" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "blog" : "blog" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "rules_core_twitter_actions_set_status_action" : { "message" : "[node:title] [node:url]", "sender" : "[current user]" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did configure post setting to display on blogs and, when I publish a new blog post, I get a message the the blog was posted to twitter but nothing shows up on the twitter page.  I'm somewhat new to Drupal and I haven't used rules before but I'll give your second suggestion a try.

Comment: Check recent log messages under reports for the error message. That will help you debug.